# Filtering Questions received max Answers in last 24 hours

Tags: python, django

Here's the model,

```
class Question(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    ....

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

How can I filter out the questions which received maximum answers in last 24 hours. How it can I filter them out?

Please help me. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

To filter questions with answers more recent than a certain date you could do something like this:

```
Question.objects.select_related().filter(
    answer__timestamp__gt=<datetime obj 24h ago>)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count_subquery = Answer.object.filter(question=OuterRef('pk'), timestamp__gt=<queried_datetime>).values('question').annotate(c=Count('*').values('c'))
Question.objects.annotate(answer_count=Subquery(count_subquery)).order_by('answer_count')
```

Comment: Sir it says 'Count' object has no attribute 'values'. What should i do?